# aggregate local events in AD

Tags: active-directory, login, windows-event-log, eventviewer

How can I aggregate events from event viewer log (logins with local Administrator) from all computers (atleast the servers - 2003,2008,2008r2) in an AD domain?

Answer (score 1):

[SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx)